# SparkSQL "CASE WHEN THEN" with two table columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two temporary tables `table_a` and `table_b` and trying to get this query and all of its conditions to work properly.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN b.id ELSE a.id END id,
    CASE WHEN a.num IS NULL THEN b.num ELSE a.num END num,
    CASE WHEN a.testdate IS NULL THEN b.testdate ELSE a.testdate END testdate
FROM table_a a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b b
    ON (a.id=b.id AND a.num=b.num AND a.testdate=b.testdate)
WHERE
    (CASE WHEN a.t_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.t_amt END)
    <>
    (CASE WHEN b.t_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.t_amt END) OR
    (CASE WHEN a.qty IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.qty END)
    <>
    (CASE WHEN b.qty IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.qty END)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN b.id ELSE a.id END,
    CASE WHEN a.num IS NULL THEN b.num ELSE a.num END,
    CASE WHEN a.testdate IS NULL THEN b.testdate ELSE a.testdate END
```

Executing the above query on these two tables using `SparkSQL` produces the following error

```
sqlq = <the sql from above>

df = sqlContext.sql(sqlq)
```

> "AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`a.id`' given input columns: [id, num, testdate];"

Comment: I've given you an answer that will likely work, but expanding your question with some context or a description of your tables and what you're trying to achieve would help getting better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your error is in the `ORDER BY` clause, as it has no concept of tables `a` and `b`, but only the names and aliases in the `SELECT` clause.
This makes quite good sense since you should really only order your results based on columns actually in the result set.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (CASE WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN b.id ELSE a.id END) AS id,
    (CASE WHEN a.num IS NULL THEN b.num ELSE a.num END) AS num,
    (CASE WHEN a.testdate IS NULL THEN b.testdate ELSE a.testdate END) AS testdate
FROM table_a AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b AS b
    ON (a.id=b.id AND a.num=b.num AND a.testdate=b.testdate)
WHERE
    (CASE WHEN a.t_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.t_amt END) <> (CASE WHEN b.t_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.t_amt END)
    OR
    (CASE WHEN a.qty IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.qty END) <> (CASE WHEN b.qty IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.qty END)
ORDER BY id, num, testdate
```